# Displaying scroll view full of Frames in Xamarin.Forms with XAML

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and C# and XAML and the whole thing. I'm trying to make a scroll view with multiple frames to be scrolled through. To do so, I have in a XAML file a set of Frames in a StackLayout in a ScrollView in a StackLayout in a ContentPage. When I run this XAML code, I'm getting the following exception thrown:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3e35poo8bi0za53/Screenshot%202015-01-05%2001.27.49.png?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what is your exact problem because the screenshot doesn't show much.

This exception, however, is likely caused by trying to assign more than one child elements to an element that can only support one child, such as a Frame

In your XAML look for:

```
<Frame>
  <View...>
  <View...>
</Frame>
```

Also take a look at the inner exceptions of the one you're showing in the screenshot - some times Xamarin.Forms is generous enough to mention the parent element or property